# restricting values of a parameter in methods of C#

Tags: c#, parameters

Assume I have a method with " `private void Test(byte inputParam)`" signature . I want to pass just 0, 1 and 2 to `inputParam`.

So how can I restrict `inputParam` with these values?
Of course I don't want to use Enum, do you offer any better solution?

thanks...

Comment: Are you trying to do this at compile time? I assume you know that you can just use if statements and throw an exception at runtime.

Comment: Yep, `if` condition and `ArgumentException` is the way to go IMO.

Comment: yes, I want to do this at compile time, because I work in a team, and I don't want the others make a mistake.

Comment: But why do you want to avoid the use of an Enum? You can easily get the numeric value (and the fact that they're 0, 1 and 2 makes this even easier) and you'll avoid any possible confusion with the param values.

Comment: yes, I agree, but there are just 3 elements for the parameter not more, if I use enum for parameters like this, the project get a mass. so I search for a better way to restrict parameter and just make a summery comment for using method.

Comment: @Katy Looks like these acceptable parameter values (`0`, `1` and `2`) have some special meaning within the method, so it's much more clear to use `enum` here. I don't see that as *making project a mass*.

Comment: thanks for your following, the answers show there is no way except using enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing you can get is programming to a contract with C# 4.0 and on. This is not compile time analysis but static analysis. This is very close, but still run-time.

```
private void Test(byte inputParam)
{
    Contract.Assert(inputParam < 3, "Invalid inputParam");
    ...
}
```

You can have the static checks run with the `cccheck.exe` tool as part of the CI (continuous integration) for the project, to have your colleagues aware of CI failures when they break the contracts you've added.

Answer (score 3):

If you need compile time check `enum` is the only way to go.

If you're OK with runtime check, you can easily add `if` statement as a very first thing in your method:

```
if(inputParam > 2)
    throw new ArgumentException("inputParam");
```